# DisplayFormat in mvc for set date format

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have in my model class a property of type DateTime. How can I render it in a specific format - for example returns MM/dd/yyyy?

I have tried this in Model...

```
    [DisplayName("Activation Date")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ActivationDate {get;set;}
```

I can not remove time !!!
I want to do that with DisplayFormat 
why this`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]`
is not working??

In my View I have

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActivationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivationDate)
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you have in your View?

Comment: I add view code above

Comment: Do you need to format this data for validation Purpose ?

Comment: yes also I want to know why DisplayFormat dose not work?

Comment: It works for me, I don't have any problem.

Comment: for me dose not work. I do not know why??

Comment: Do you have an EditorTemplate for DateTime in your EditorTemplates folder?

Comment: Try using TextBoxFor helper instead of EditorFor helper see if that fixes anything...

Answer (score 0):

All above code is correct .My visual studio 2010 had problem. I use visual studio 2012.